# ROracle hanging, how can I cancel the query

Tags: oracle, r

When I execute a query on `R` using `ROracle`, sometimes the query seems to hang, I cannot stop doing `CTRL+C` or hitting `ESC`.
Is there something I can do (R.2.15.2 on Win7) to stop the query and return to `R>`

Answer (score 1):

One trick I have used for uninterruptible R code in the past is to call it within a call to `parallel::mcparallel`. Then if it hangs, I can kill the forked process and keep going in the main R process. Example:

```
function.that.hangs <- function(...) system("while true; do echo hello; sleep 1; done")

# This might hang
result <- function.that.hangs(...)

# Do this instead, the run the function in a forked process.
p <- mcparallel(function.that.might.hang(...))
# This might still hang, but you can kill the stuck R process and it will return.
result <- mmcollect(p)[[1]]
```

(This example probably doesn't stop you from using CTRL+C, but you get the idea.

Comment: => it looks good, but I am on Windows which is not a POSIX system so I cannot fork a process... (can I ?). Also there is an option when I instanciate the Oracle client `oracle(interruptible=TRUE)`, but strangely `CTRL-C` still does not work

Comment: Sorry, I believe the parallel package is UNIX (POSIX?) only.

Comment: that's my understanding (well parallel works on Windows but not forking parallelization) ;) too bad, while we are on it, have you ever benchmark ROracle against running the same queries in SAS for instance, it looks slow to me (but it might be network problem)

Comment: No, I don't do database stuff much. I was giving an answer for the general case of "function that hangs", with nothing specific to databases.